# Why does newtons method in optimisation converge in one step for a quadratic function?

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson

According to the [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) page for Newton's method in optimization, using newton's method to find $min_{x \in R} f(x)$ for a twice differentiable function $f: R \rightarrow R$, the exact extremum can be found in one step if $f$ happens to be quadratic. Why ?

Comment: can you show the result after one iteration for a quadratic function?

Comment: That's what the answer by Charles McCharles shows, but my point is how can it be generalised ?

Comment: repeat the steps of Charles for $f(x) = x^TAx + b^Tx + c$ where you assume $A$ is psd

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x) = c(x - a)^2 + b$.
Notice $f'(x) = 2c(x-a)$ and $f''(x) = 2c$.
Plug into the formula: $x_1 = x_0 - \frac{2c(x_0-a)}{2c} = x_0 - (x_0 - a) = a$.

Comment: Right, but how would we generalise it for any quadratic function ? For eg. functions with >2 variables.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the definition of a quadratic function. For example, $f(x,y) = xy$ is quadratic in the sense of "degree two", but it doesn't have a minimum.

Comment: Maybe you're saying it can find a zero of a general quadratic polynomial $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in one step. I guess I haven't thought deeply enough about the problem.

Comment: the statement is about a *convex* quadratic function

Comment: Yes, so how do we generalise the statement to convex quadratic functions ?

Comment: @mahesh Rao   For a scalar function $f$ of multiple variables the statement is analogous if $f$ is its [second-order Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quadratic $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac 1 2 x^T A x$ with $A$ positive definite, we have $f'(x) = Ax$ and $f''(x) = A$ (can be verified using Taylor series).

Since Newton's step starting at $x_0$ is $x_0 + p$ where $p = - f''(x)^{-1} f'(x) = - A^{-1} A x = -x$, we can see that $f'(x_0 + p)=f'(x_0 - x_0) = f'(0)=0$, so this is the global minimum after one step.